# remove empty objects from the Django query results

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I want to remove those stores from the result which do not have coupons,My models.py is as follows..
This is store model and i want to remove every store which do not have any corresponding coupon data

```
class stores(models.Model):
    """ This is the store model """
    storeName = models.CharField(max_length=15)                                          # Store Name
    storeDescription = models.TextField()                                                # Store Description
    storeURL = models.URLField()                                                         # Store URL
    storePopularityNumber = models.IntegerField(choices=PRIORITY_CHOICES,default=3)      # Store Popularity Number  
    storeImage = models.ImageField(upload_to="images")                                   # Store Image 
    storeSlug = models.CharField(max_length=400)                                         # This is the text you see in the URL
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)                                  # Time at which store is created
    updatedAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)                                      # Time at which store is updated
    storeTags = models.ManyToManyField(tags)                                             # All the tags associated with the store
```

coupon model is:

```
class coupons(models.Model):
    """ This is the coupon model """
    couponTitle = models.CharField(max_length=100,default="")
    couponCode = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    couponValue = models.CharField(max_length=50)                             # Coupon value in RS.
    couponDescription = models.TextField()                                    # Coupon Description
    couponURL = models.URLField(default='http://www.foo.com')                 # Coupon click URL
    couponStore = models.ForeignKey(stores,on_delete=models.PROTECT)          # Key of coupon to store
    couponTags = models.ManyToManyField(tags)                                 # Tag names associated to coupon
    success = models.TextField(default=' ')                                   # Count of the number of times people have made it work
    failures =  models.TextField(default=' ')                                 # Count of the number of times this has failed
    lastTested = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)                          # When was the coupon last tested
    updatedAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    addedOn = models.DateTimeField()
    active =  models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Can any body help me please...I need to exclude all the stores which does not have related coupon data....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to set related_name explicitly:

```
class coupons(models.Model):
    # ...
    couponStore = models.ForeignKey(stores, on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                                    related_name='coupons')
    # ...
```

Then stores, than have coupons:

```
stores.objects.exclude(coupons=None)
```

Comment: No i can't do this as i have other related models to store that i did not shown above to keep the question to the point....I am querying ...store related coupon data through this query : `def StoreCoupons(self):
        for t in stores.objects.filter(storeName=self.storeName):
            return ",".join([str(a.couponTitle) for a in t.coupons_set.all()])` is their any similar concept to remove the stores that do not have coupon related to it just from the query result.....

Comment: Myabe you need something like this: `def StoreCoupons(self): for t in stores.objects.exclude(coupons=None).filter(storeName=self.storeName): return ",".join([str(a.couponTitle) for a in t.coupons.all()])` Assuming, that `couponStore` field has `related_name='coupons'`

Comment: can you show the entire model definition? Or just rename related_name to smth else, for example `related_name='store_coupons'`

Comment: Well, i don't see any error, that may happen. Try either set related_name to smth (for example `coupons`) and use it everywhere instead of `coupons_set`, either not set related_name and use `coupons_set` as field reference, but in query still use `coupons`: stores.objects.exclude(coupons=None).